# JBPM 5 - HowTo deregister task-event-handlers from TaskService

Tags: jbpm

When a stateful-knowledge-session is created/loaded, work-item-handlers are registered with it.

Human-task work-item-handler, in turn registers event-response-handlers for task-events with TaskService.

In a scenario, where one session is used for each process-instance (one session per process-instance) & a singleton TaskService, how to de-register the task-event response-handlers from the TaskService ?

Answer (score 0):

You should dispose your handler:
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/5.4.0.Final/jbpm-human-task/jbpm-human-task-core/src/main/java/org/jbpm/process/workitem/wsht/GenericHTWorkItemHandler.java#L165

Comment: In the case, when `GenericHTWorkItemHandler.dispose() --> LocalTaskService.unregisterForEvent()` called will it not remove ALL the `EventTriggerTransport` registered for the key in the TaskService ?? GenericHTWorkItemHandler always creates equal key with `taskId=-1`. Sorry if my doubt is very basic